# jQuery toggle animation

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle

I have this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#panel").hide();

   $('.login').toggle(
   function()
   {
      $('#panel').animate({
      height: "150", 
      padding:"20px 0",
      backgroundColor:'#000000',
      opacity:.8
}, 500);
   },
   function()
   {
      $('#panel').animate({
      height: "0", 
      padding:"0px 0",
      opacity:.2
      }, 500);
   });
});
```

This is working fine, but I need to extend the functionality a little.  I want to also similarly manipulate another div's properties in sync with the #panel div.  I tried adding two more functions relating to the secondary div, but I just got a 4-phase toggle...haha!
Forgive my ignorance!

Thanks guys!

Comment: Why can't you add the code to manipulate this second DIV inside the first two functions? Am I missing something?

Comment: No, I was missing it! I'm a jscript noob.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
$('.login').toggle(
    function(){
        $('#panel').animate({
            height: "150", 
            padding:"20px 0",
            backgroundColor:'#000000',
            opacity:.8
        }, 500);
        $('#otherdiv').animate({
            //otherdiv properties here
        }, 500);
    },
    function(){
        $('#panel').animate({
            height: "0", 
            padding:"0px 0",
            opacity:.2
        }, 500);     
        $('#otherdiv').animate({
            //otherdiv properties here
        }, 500);
});
```

Comment: This function is deprecated as of JQuery 1.8 and removed in JQuery 1.9. http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/#entry-longdesc

Answer (score 6):

I dont think adding dual functions inside the toggle function works for a registered click event (Unless I'm missing something)

For example:

```
$('.btnName').click(function() {
 top.$('#panel').toggle(function() {
   $(this).animate({ 
     // style change
   }, 500);
   },
   function() {
   $(this).animate({ 
     // style change back
   }, 500);
 });
```

Comment: so, what are you trying to say ? i dont think it is helpful to give code that dosent work and say "Oh, it dosent work". post a real solution.

Comment: I think it is helpful to give code that dosent work and say "Oh, it dosent work".

Comment: This function is deprecated as of JQuery 1.8 and removed in JQuery 1.9. http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/#entry-longdesc

Answer (score 1):

Use toggle() or slideToggle from jquery:

[Toggle](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

```
  $( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
      $( "#book" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });


 <div id="clickme">
      Click here
    </div>
    <img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123">
```

Answer (score -8):

```
onmouseover="$('.play-detail').stop().animate({'height': '84px'},'300');" 

onmouseout="$('.play-detail').stop().animate({'height': '44px'},'300');"
```

Just put two stops -- one onmouseover and one onmouseout.

Comment: Using inline JavaScript is not a good pattern. If you are already using jQuery use event handlers instead.