# Jquery toggle on custom animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation, toggle

I have this animation which I'd like to trigger upon click of a link. When I run the animations separately, it's working fine. But using the jquery `toggle()`, it doesn't work anymore. Can anyone easily see why?

Without `toggle()` it works (ran each separately):

```
$('#sign-in-fx').click(function() {
    $('.login_form').animate({ width: '273' }, 'slow', 'easeInOutQuart');
    //$('.login_form').animate({ width: '1' }, 'slow', 'easeInOutQuart');
});
```

With `toggle()` nothing happens:

```
$('#sign-in-fx').click(function() {
    $('.login_form').toggle(
        function() {
            $(this).animate({ width: '273' }, 'slow', 'easeInOutQuart')
        },
        function() {
            $(this).animate({ width: '1' }, 'slow', 'easeInOutQuart')
        }
    );
});
```

This is similar to [jQuery toggle animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931113/jquery-toggle-animation)

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ Looks like you are using `toggle()` function incorrectly.

Comment: @Grzegorz It is related to http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I think this is what you originally wanted to do:

```
$('#sign-in-fx').toggle(
        function() {
            $('.login_form').animate({ width: '273' }, 'slow', 'easeInOutQuart')
        },
        function() {
            $('.login_form').animate({ width: '1' }, 'slow', 'easeInOutQuart')
        }
);
```

You were calling `toggle()` on the element to animate, but it has to be called on the element that will receive the `click` event.

Comment: The sama answer i wanted to post :)

Comment: Actually I answer the same, giving some notes and providing a working code. But may be a bit late :)

Comment: @Nelson I know this is an old answer, but the way you're using `toggle()`, is deprecated. Please edit, or remove your answer so as not to confuse people

Answer (score 1):

`toggle()` used the way you are using it, is [**deprecated**](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)!

Use a flag, and toggle the animated width directly, like so:

```
var flag = true;

$('#sign-in-fx').on('click', function() {
    $('.login_form').stop(true, true)
                    .animate({ width: flag?'273':'1' }, 'slow', 'easeInOutQuart');
    flag=!flag;
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HUHfk/1/)

Or if you don't like globals, you can always use data() :

```
$('#sign-in-fx').on('click', function() {
    var flag = $('.login_form').data('flag')!=undefined?$('.login_form').data('flag'):true;
    $('.login_form').stop(true, true)
                    .animate({ width: flag?'273':'1' }, 'slow', 'easeInOutQuart')
                    .data('flag', !flag);
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HUHfk/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also do as follows:

```
$('#sign-in-fx').click(function() {
    if (! $('.login_form').is(':animated')) { //if no animation running
       if ($('.login_form').width() > 1) {
          $('.login_form').animate({ width: '1' }, 'slow', 'easeInOutQuart');
       } else {
         $('.login_form').animate({ width: '273' }, 'slow', 'easeInOutQuart');
       }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is done on `document.ready`? Your code seems fine.

```
    $(function () {
      $('.login_form').toggle(
          function() {
              $(this).animate({ width: '273' }, 'slow', 'easeInOutQuart')
          },
          function() {
              $(this).animate({ width: '1' }, 'slow', 'easeInOutQuart')
          }
      );
    });
```

Comment: It is. I can't really think of a good reason why it's not working unless there's some typo I'm too tired to see..

Comment: Look the edit of this answer - it works like that! `.toogle()` checks for a click and executes the functions(handlers) added one by one ... they could be more than 2.  In your code you are clicking other link.