# JS script not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

JS code:

```
function showCaption() {
    var captionVis = $('.grey-box-caption-text').css('display');    
    if(captionVis = "none") {
      $('.grey-box-caption-text').width(0);
      $(this).find('.grey-box-caption-text').show().animate({'width': '464px'},750);}
    } else {
      $(this).find('.grey-box-caption-text').animate({'width': '0'},750,
                                                     function(){$(this).hide();});  
    }
};

$('.caption-container').click(function() {
    showCaption();
    return false;   
    }
 );
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="one-half column home-three-img">
   <div class="caption-container">
      <div class="grey-box-caption">
      </div>
      <div class="grey-box-caption-text">This is a caption test - Hopefully this works
      </div>
   </div>
   <img src="images/3.jpg">
</div>
```

This won't work and I'm a JS noob. Please help.

I'm trying to get the caption section to slide out from the left to the right. When i click on the parent container nothing happens. I'm expecting the caption to shoot out and hide when I click again.

I have Jquery loaded properly and have a document.ready function that works.

Link to the WIP http://clients.pivotdesign.com/dev/annual_report_2014/index.html

Comment: It's hard to make a question more ambiguous than to just say _"it doesn't work"_ without any explanation.

Comment: What EXACTLY doesn't work? What DOES it do?

Comment: Sorry I really have no idea what's wrong with it. I edited my post though

Comment: You need to include the relevant HTML with your JS.

Comment: I can't get the caption section to slide out to the right

Comment: When you have a JavaScript problem, the very first thing to do is check the browser console for errors.

Comment: First you should [lint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint) your code...

Comment: I think the last answer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059201/jquery-toggle-on-custom-animation) is what you want. Check the first jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A big problem is that the value of `this` won't be set in your "showCaption" function. Add a `return false;` to the end of that function:

```
function showCaption(){
    var captionVis = $('.grey-box-caption-text').css('display');    
    if (captionVis == "none") {
        $('.grey-box-caption-text').width(0);
        $(this).find('.grey-box-caption-text').show().animate({'width': '464px'},750);
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('.grey-box-caption-text').animate({'width': '0'},750, function(){
            $(this).hide();
        }); 
    }
};
```

and then change the handler assignment to:

```
$('.caption-container').click(showCaption);
```

Also note that your test in that `if` statement was incorrect: use `==` or `===` for comparison.

Comment: Will you show me the js I tried implementing this and it wasn't working. I think I may have entered it incorrectly

Comment: @alcoven that *is* the JS. Have you checked the browser console to see if there are errors?  There was a problem with a stray `}` in your original source, and the browser would complain about that.

Comment: Ok so got rid of the stray but now it's adding width:15px to my div and that width is not specified anywhere ;[

Comment: @alcoven that sounds like a different issue.

Comment: @alcoven [here is a working CodePen](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/KwpzMm)

Comment: Yeah, Idk why this is happening. It's definitely from the JS though. It only happens on .click please help me. Let me know if you can check the site. My css and html should be perfect, it's just my JS.

Comment: Thank you so much @Pointy You rule! just one question. Why does the the click function have to be set up with $("body").onclick("click", ...

Comment: @alcoven it doesn't; I just did that out of habit. If you do it your way, make sure you set it up in a "ready" handler.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the CodePen from Pointy a bit and it should do the same with less code.

Why the gray box increases the height here in the SO demo, I don't know. In [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEVNzv) it works with-out this "bug".

```js
function showCaption() {
  var $graybox = $('.grey-box-caption-text');

  $graybox.animate({
    width: 'toggle',
    opacity: 'toggle'
  }, 'slow');
};

$(function(){
 $("#wrapper").on("click", showCaption);
});
```

```css
.grey-box-caption {
  min-height: 3em;
  min-width: 20px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  display: inline-block;
}
.grey-box-caption-text {
  display: none;
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class=grey-box-caption>
    <div class=grey-box-caption-text>
      Hello World this is some text.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice! I'm now working making this work with multiple $greybox using $(this). You just killed it with that clean JS though.