# Jquery .toggle .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I want to .toggle an .animation. Can you help me figure out why this jquery code does not work?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Em682/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.adiv').toggle(
   function(){
    $(this).animate({
        width: "150",
        height: "150",
    }, 1000);
    },
    function(){
    $(this).animate({
        width: "77", 
        height: "77",
    }, 1000);        
});
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You do realize the toggle is for show or hide. not to toggle something.

Comment: Thanks @EasyBB was trying to follow the [method here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931113/jquery-toggle-animation). Any other ways to achieve this though? I appreciate your input

Comment: Yes you can do that, it's two different "toggles" per say for the show hide basically. I'll show you

Comment: Also, code works fine... you need to select the Jquery library from the sidebar :)

Comment: That version of toggle was deprecated and removed from jQuery, the question you're looking at is five years old.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! Very helpful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/sirodego/1/edit

```
$('#toggle').toggle(function(){
    $(this).animate({
       width: "150",
       height: "150",
    }, 1000);
  },function(){
 $(this).animate({
     width: "77", 
     height: "77",
 }, 1000);        
});
```

This works fine, for the first condition which would be either to hide or show which would be the first animate, then do the opposite which would be the second animate.

If you need it to do more please let me know. My fiddle shows what is going on for you.

Answer (score 0):

Attention: Your code works great! The problem is very simple: in your jsfiddle, your forget to import jquery! Use the sidebar on the left and try again!

Btw here is my solution using mouseover and mouseout:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Em682/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.adiv').mouseover(function()
     {$(this).animate({
            width: "150",
            height: "150"
        }, 1000);
    }).mouseout(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width: "77", 
            height: "77"
        }, 1000);        
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.adiv').click( function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).animate({
            width: "30",
            height: "30",
        }, 1000);
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    }  
    else{
        $(this).animate({
            width: "150", 
            height: "150",
        }, 1000);
    $(this).addClass('active');        
     };
  });      
});
```

Check This [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/Em682/4/)

Comment: The OP's toggle works fine, I just don't believe he has told us very well on what he is trying to achieve.