# jquery how to toggle this specific animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

So I want to toggle this animation in jQuery but I found it very hard to find a way.

```
$( "#console" ).animate({height: "20px"});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931113/jquery-toggle-animation Should be helpful to you

Comment: when you need to toggle it, continuously..or...?

Comment: @Pushpendra : `toggle` is deprecated as of JQuery 1.8 and removed in JQuery 1.9

Comment: toggle a class instead, handling animation in CSS. EDIT: as you seem to use jQuery UI, this would be easier using [toggleClass()](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/) and passing relevant parameters to enable animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `height` of element in variable and use it to animate. Also you need to save `toggle` state to having animation without bug.

```js
var firstHeight = $("div").height();
$("div").click(function(){
    $(this).stop();
    if (!$(this).data("animateToggle"))
        $("div").data("animateToggle", 1).animate({height: "200px"});
    else       
        $("div").removeData("animateToggle").animate({height: firstHeight});
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```